# How can I set the number of bytes to be displayed by the binary form of a character in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

I want to be able to set the number of bytes displayed by each character in the string to be 6. Here, the string is `jJ` and I'm getting the output as `1000111001`. `J` is giving `1001` and I want it to display `001001` instead.

```
a = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','+','/']
def mapFirst(string):
   return ''.join(bin(ord(chr(a.index(c)))) for c in string).replace('0b','')

def main():
    k = 'jJ'
    print(mapFirst(k))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python encode hex pad every character with 00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36245327/python-encode-hex-pad-every-character-with-00)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
return ''.join(bin(ord(chr(a.index(c)))) for c in string).replace('0b','')
```

With:

```
return ''.join(str(bin(ord(chr(a.index(c))))).replace('0b','').zfill(6) for c in string)
```

The function you were looking for is `zfill(width)`

---

**Note**: I suggest you to split that line into multiple lines for readability purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Add binary value 1000000 and extract the last 6 binary digits.  This will ensure that there are always at least 6 trailing digits in the result of bin().

```
bin((1<<6)+a.index(c))[-6:]

or

bin(64+a.index(c))[-6:]
```

for example:

```
bin((1<<6)+a.index("j"))[-6:] #--> '001001'
```